# Connecting a third monitor to System76 Ubuntu laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a System76 with an HDMI port, which I currently use for a second monitor. Ideally, I'd like to connect a third monitor and then turn off the laptop's screen as it's not great for my posture.

My research suggested I couldn't just buy an HDMI -> USB converter so I bought an external adapter [from Amazon](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LZYKDMS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1), however, it doesn't work.

It's quite galling that it's a bit more expensive but doesn't work. Is this the right product? Is it possible to have three monitors coming off one Ubuntu laptop?

Help most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's probably DisplayLink based. Please confirm with `lsusb`. If it is then all you need to do is install drivers. It's only plug'n'play in Windows 10.

Comment: I've installed the drivers but, unfortunately, it still doesn't work @ChanganAuto. `lsusb` shows the device when connected but the monitor doesn't seem to receive input.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `lsusb` to your question